# Tagging Qt Widgets

Tags: c++, qt, tagging, qpushbutton, qt5.3

Is it possible to tag Qt Widgets? I am generating QPushButtons programmatically and as far as I know, there is no way to differentiate them. I checked the documentation and couldn't find anything. What would be an alternative?

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        QPushButton *s = new QPushButton("Select");
        ...
    }
```

Comment: see my edit please. I improved my answer a little bit, maybe you find it useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I was after :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way is to set object name to this buttons. For example.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    QPushButton *s = new QPushButton("Select");
    s->setObjectName("But" + QString::number(i));
}
```

Also you can `setProperty()` to button and read it in future by `property()` method

Edit:

Moreover you can set not unique objectNames. Suppose you want set background color for some buttons. Then you shoudn't apply stylesheet for this buttons yourself. Just set same objectName to this buttons.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    QPushButton *s = new QPushButton("Select");
    if(i%2 == 0)
         s->setObjectName("red");
}
```

And apply next styleSheet

```
#red
{
    background-color: red
}
```

And this buttons will be painted in red color.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the button address as a key in a std::map to a value containing say a structure with information about the control.